# Non existence of a non singular vector field on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Prove that the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$, $T^1 S^2$, is not diffeomorphic to $S^2×S^1$ by showing that if so there exists a nowhere vanishing vector field on $S^2$

I do not know how to create that vector field.

Thank you

Comment: Are you actually asking if $T^1S^2$ is not isomorphic as fiber bundle over $S^2$ to $S^2\times S^1$ or that $T^1S^2$ is not diffeomorphic, as manifold, to $S^2\times S^1$ ?

Comment: Hello Bebop, thanks for your help, i am asking as manifolds

Comment: It would help if you let us know how much algebraic topology do you know. For instance, do you know how to compute the second homotopy group or the fundamental group if a fiber bundle? (Long exact sequence of a fibration.)

Comment: You specifically want a proof that uses the nonexistence of a global section $S^2 \to T^1 S^2$? Because there are simple proofs using $\pi_1$ or $H_1$, among other things.

Comment: dear @bebop I know nothing about alg top, just vector fields

Comment: As explained in my answer, if you are not talking about bundle, then being diffeomorphic has nothing to do with vector fields because this notion is not preserved by a diffeo in general. Do you know de Rham cohomology or other invariants of manifold ?

Comment: Unfortunately I just know vector fields.

Comment: So it seems to me that your question can't be about diffeomorphism but just about proving that the unit tangent bundle $T^1S^2$ is not trivial.

Comment: Actually the question is: Prove that if there existe a vector field without zeros, then $T^1S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$. As $T^1S^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$, no such a vector field exists.

Comment: Ok, now I see. So you actually don't need any knowledge of algebraic topology. I will edit my answer to give a short proof of this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is clear that $p:T^1S^2\rightarrow S^2$ and $q:S^2\times S^1\rightarrow S^2$, as bundle, are not isomorphic. Indeed, if so, it would exist two diffeomorphism $f,g$ so that the following diagram :
$$\begin{array}{ccc}T^1S^2 & \underset{f}\rightarrow & S^2\times S^1 \\ \downarrow & \circlearrowright & \downarrow \\ S^2 & \underset{g}\rightarrow & S^2\end{array}$$
is commutative.

Since the map $s:S^2\rightarrow S^2\times S^1, x\mapsto (x,1)$ is a smooth section of $q$ i.e. $q\circ s=id$ and the diagram commutes, the map $s'=f^{-1}\circ s\circ g:S^2\rightarrow T^1S^2$ has to be a smooth section of $p$. So, we found a nonvanishing global vector field of the $2$-sphere, which is impossible.

Now, as manifold, $T^1S^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$. You can see that here, you can't use the above trick because a section $s:S^2\rightarrow S^2\times S^1$ has no reason to give a section of $T^1S^2$ via a diffeomorphism from $T^1S^2$ to $S^2\times S^1$.

Here is a easy way to understand why $T^1S^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$. Actually, you will see that they are not even homeomorphic.

Let us see $T^1S^2$ as $$T^1S^2=\{(x,v)\in \mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3 \ | \ \|x\|=\|v\|=1, \langle x,v\rangle=0\}.$$
So, a point in $T^1S^2$ is a pair of unitary and orthogonal vectors of $\mathbb R^3$. Then, the map $$\begin{array}{rcl}T^1S^2 & \longrightarrow & SO(3) \\ (x,v) & \longmapsto & \text{Matrix}(x,v,x\times v) \end{array}$$
is well defined, continuous and bijective. It gives us a homeomorphism (or diffeomorphism). Hence if $T^1S^2$ is diffeomorphic or homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$ then so is $SO(3)$.

But their fundamental group doesn't coincide :

- $\pi_1(S^2\times S^1)\simeq \pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$,
- $\pi_1(SO(3))=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Actually, $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb RP^3$. You can prove it using quaternions for example or Lie group theory on $SU(2)$ or even directly :

Let $f$ be the map given by $$\begin{array}{rcl} D^3 & \longrightarrow & SO(3) \\  x & \longmapsto & \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \text{Rot}(x,\theta(x)) & \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\ I_3 & \text{ if } x=0 \end{array} \right.\end{array}$$
where

- $D^3$ is the unit closed ball in $\mathbb R^3$
- $I_3$ is the identity matrix,
- $\text{Rot}(x,\theta(x))$ is the rotation of $\mathbb R^3$ whose axis is $\mathbb Rx$ oriented by $x$ and angle is $\|x\|\pi$.

This map is continuous, onto but no injective: $f(x)=f(-x)$ on the boundary of $D^3$. So it induces a continuous bijective map $\bar f:\mathbb RP^3\rightarrow SO(3)$ hence a homeomorphism.

Notice that since $\mathbb RP^3\simeq S^3/{\pm 1}$, the induced map $S^3\rightarrow SO(3)$ is a universal two-sheeted covering map and you get back $\pi_1(SO(3))$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ thus different from $\mathbb Z$.

**Edit**: Here is an explanation of your last question :

> Show that if there exists a non vanishing vector field on $S^2$ then
>   $T^1S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1.$

Let $s:S^2\rightarrow TS^2$ be such a vector field. Since it does not vanish, one can assume that for any $p\in S^2$, $\|s(p)\|=1$. Now, following the same trick as before, $s(p)$ is orthogonal to $p$ so $n(p)=p\times s(p)$ is also a smooth unitary vector field on $S^2$ and for any $p\in S^2$, $(s(p),n(p))$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pS^2$.

Let $\phi:S^2\times \mathbb R^2\rightarrow TS^2$  be the map given by $\phi(p,(x,y))=xs(p)+yn(p)$.

You can easily check that $\phi$ is injective, smooth and onto. Furthermore, using the fact that $(s(p),n(p))$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pS^2$, $\phi$ is actually a diffeomorphism. (This is a classical fact that any vector bundle of rank $n$ is trivial iff it has $n$ linearly independent global sections.)

Finally, $$\begin{align*}\phi^{-1}(T^1S^2) & =\{(p,(x,y))\in S^2\times \mathbb R^2 \ | \ \|xs(p)+yn(p)\|=1\} \\ & = \{(p,(x,y))\in S^2\times \mathbb R^2 \ | \ \|xs(p)+yn(p)\|^2=1\} \\ & = \{(p,(x,y))\in S^2\times \mathbb R^2 \ | \ x^2\|s(p)\|^2+y^2\|n(p)\|^2=1\} \\ & = \{(p,(x,y))\in S^2\times \mathbb R^2 \ | \ x^2+y^2=1\} \\ & = S^2\times S^1.\end{align*}$$

So if there exists a non vanishing vector field of $S^2$, then $TS^2$ has to be diffeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb R^2$ and $T^1S^2$ to $S^2\times S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement to @Bebop's great answer: We can also compute $\pi_1(T^1S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ using van Kampen's theorem. The closed hemispheres $U$ and  $L$ of $S^2$ allow us to break $T^1 S^2$ into circle bundles $T^1 U \sqcup_\phi T^1 L$, glued along some attaching map $\phi$. Since $T^1 U$ and $T^1 L$ are conveniently isomorphic to solid tori $S^1 \times D^2$ glued along their boundary tori $S^1 \times S^1$, we can analyze the attaching map and fundamental group in the same way we would analyze a lens space.  By inspection and van Kampen's theorem (or the fact that $T^1 S^2$ and $L(2,1)$ are homeomorphic)  we have $\pi_1(T^1 S^2) \cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.